# Why doesn't the Arcanist's arcane reservoir fill completely each day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

Do anyone know the reason why the Arcanist arcane reservoir does not fill completely like the other pool types I can think of (monk ki pool, magus arcana pool, gunslinger grit pool, ...)?

I'm trying to think of reasons, but have thought of nothing good.

[Arcane Reservoir](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist)

> An arcanist has an innate pool of magical energy that she can draw upon to fuel her arcanist exploits and enhance her spells. The arcanist's arcane reservoir can hold a maximum amount of magical energy equal to 3 + the arcanist's level. Each day, when preparing spells, the arcanist's arcane reservoir fills with raw magical energy, gaining a number of points equal to 3 + 1/2 her arcanist level. Any points she had from the previous day are lost. She can also regain these points through the consume spells class feature and some arcanist exploits. The arcane reservoir can never hold more points than the maximum amount noted above; points gained in excess of this total are lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### I think it's just phrased poorly.

The Arcanist *does* get her pool refilled each day - to 3 + 1/2 her Arcanist level. She can, however, gain up to 1/2 her Arcanist level additional points *beyond* that normal "maximum" through the consume spells class feature and some Arcanist exploits. Points gained beyond that total (3 + 1/2 level normal, plus 1/2 level again extra) are lost.

Comment: Whats the point of the extra pool size? Im happy being able to refill a pool that I have emptied, but when its not "full" at the start of the day I feel kindof ripped off.

Comment: The point is that you can save up points early during the day to use later on.

Comment: @Fering It's sort of like an overcharge limit. For all intents and purposes, 3 + 1/2 your arcanist level IS your pool at "full", but it can be "overfilled" to an extent, too.